# how do I apply a wieght to a bone?

Tags: animation, matrix

If I were to assign every vertex to a bone/matrix, how would I edit the transformation matrix so some of the vertexes are transformed less?

For example, if I have the *matrix*

```
cos sin  0 0
-sin cos 0 2
0    0   1 0
0    0   0 1
```

What do i do to it to make the vertex rotate less?

Comment: Those sin and cos terms are all supposed to be supplied with an angle.  *eg* `sin(theta)`.  So, since you are most likely in control of that, just reduce the angle.  If not, you can recover the angle via `asin` or `acos`, reduce it, then apply the sin or cos again.

Comment: Thanks, but please post this as an answer so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting paddy
"Those sin and cos terms are all supposed to be supplied with an angle. eg sin(theta). So, since you are most likely in control of that, just reduce the angle."
So change the angle by multiplying by a value -1 to 1 and that will change the direction/amount it changes.